# Would working reduced hours or part time something that senior engineers would be interested in?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, career-development

I work for a tech company and we're trying to see if there is interest from senior engineers who want to work part time. Now that we're a remote first company, we want to know if there are engineers who are at a point in their career where they no longer want to work full time, but are still interested in working reduced hours or part time. Specifically, we're not so much looking for contractors/freelancers to work on specific projects, but for an experienced senior engineer (previously worked for different start ups, or at a larger top tech company) to join a team and essentially be a guru or advisor to the team.

What are peoples thoughts on this idea? Is this type of thing something that you've seen at other companies, or would be of interest to see at a company?

Comment: You will need to ask the senior engineers at your company. The opinions of the people here don't matter much.

Comment: After working remotely is a thing now, IMHO working only 4 days a week is the next step. There is actually a job portal for jobs like that: https://4dayweek.io/

Comment: Less time, with same pay?  Sounds like a good offer to me.

Comment: Yes it is a good idea, which is why I have done it.  I now only work 4 days a week.  It's nice having an employer who allows you to make the choice.

Comment: I belive we should focus on what values is created and not how many hours we work. We are not working in a factory where all hours create the same value. At least for me, i dont want to work a place where the definition of values created is defined by the numbers of hours we work.

Answer (score 2):

I am actually leaving an organization right now for this exact reason... almost no one hires people in my role as anything less than 40-50+ hours per week.

But for me, I went and moved down to Mexico and have been working remotely. I don't need to work more than 5 hours per week to meet my budget.... So I saved up my money for over a year working full time, saving 90%+ of my income, and just announced to the team that I'll be retiring out here for good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I've seen quite a few cases of senior engineers who aren't ready to retire, still want to keep in touch, and are incredible contributors - but don't necessarily want to keep working long hours. The good ones make great mentors in more junior teams. Either part-time or as consultants.

What I can't answer is whether you'll find any in your particular organization/culture/context - or whether they'll be interested in the conditions you offer.

Answer (score 0):

There are programs like this. They allow people to reduce their hours for a year or two while preparing to retire. This gives them an opportunity to make a transition, while also giving them the opportunity to mentor their replacements.

These programs work best when they are long time employees retiring, instead of people hired just for mentor ships. That way they are also passing on their institutional knowledge, without having to cram it into a two week notice period.

The big issue is how to handle benefits. Once the hours drop below a certain number of hours the local laws might not require the company to pay benefits. But the employee might need insurance coverage and access to pension and other retirement programs. The question of time-in-service also can become an issue, related to vacation and retirement. Some places allow the employee to collect retirement benefits while also getting a salary.